# Surprising necessary condition for a "shift-invariant" determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a $4\ x\ 4$ binary matrix and $Z=\pmatrix {s&s&s&s \\ s&s&s&s \\s&s&s&s \\s&s&s&s}$

Then $\det(A+Z)=\det(A)=1\ $ (independent of s, so $\det(A)$ is "shift-invariant") can only
 hold if the number of zeros in $A$ is exact 8.
 This condition is not sufficient because only $72$ out of the $12\ 870$ matrices
 with exactly 8 zeros do the job. I checked this funny and surprising condition
 by brute force. Is there a proof without checking all $65\ 536$ matrices ?

Comment: One example of such a  matrix with "shift-invariant" determinant 1 is $$\pmatrix {1&1&0&1 \\ 1&0&0&0& \\ 0&0&0&1 \\ 1&0&1&1}$$

Comment: How many of the $12,870$ matrices with exactly $8$ zeros have determinant $1$?

Comment: Are you viewing everything over $\Bbb{F}_2$? Talk about binary matrices first left me with that impression, but then I started thinking. $A=I$ and $A'=I+Z$ are both invertible (identity+nilpotent is invertible) and thus have determinants $=1_{\Bbb{F}_2}$. So the claim does not hold ($A=A'+Z$ has 12 zeros, $A'=A+Z$ only four). You are probably calculating the determinant in $\Bbb{Z}$ anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts on your question : denote by $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ the columns of $A$. Let $V$ be the
all-ones column $(1,1,1,1)$, and let $U$ be the matrix of all
whose columns are equal to $V$ (so that $Z=sU$). Then

$\det (A + sU) = $
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
&=& [C_1+sV,C_2+sV,C_3+sV,c_4+sV] \\
&=& [C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4]  +s([V,C_2,C_3,C_4]+[C_1,V,C_3,C_4]+
[C_1,C_2,V,C_4]+[C_1,C_2,C_3,V]) 
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$

So your "shift-invariance" property $\det(A+sU)=\det(A)$ will hold iff
$$
[V,C_2,C_3,C_4]+[C_1,V,C_3,C_4]+
[C_1,C_2,V,C_4]+[C_1,C_2,C_3,V]=0
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the edit attempt. I was just trying to work at breaking up the last equality so it doesn't run into the right column of the page.

Comment: @amWhy you’re welcome.